# Android Programming with eclipse

Tags: android

my android phone is not detecting in pc even though I installed all the necessary drivers and all are up to date, can anyone tell me steps to install device in windows 7. my android phone is HTC one x.(I am running my project in eclipse indigo)

Comment: Enabled `Developer` mode in your device?

Comment: you need to install HTC Syncmanager on pc and turn on developer mode from mobile.

Comment: I have enabled developer mode and installed HTC sync manager  still its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start SDK manager
- Go To **Extra**
- See whether Have you installed *Google USB driver* if not install this.

[image]

- Restart Eclipse.
- Again Connect Your device with the following steps.

from your device check that whether have you Started *USB debugging mode* on from

- Developer Options
- Checked **USB debugging** with USB. Device should be connected as MTP.

If **Developer Option** is not available on your device you can enable it by following steps

- Go to Settings
- About Phone
- Tap Build number continue 7 to 8 times (Don't remember exact figure)
- You will see the Toast "You are now developer"
- Developer Options will be enable now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable developer option on your device?
this link might help http://www.developer.com/ws/android/connecting-your-android-device-to-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

If the aforementioned answers don't work, there is a workaround with connecting some Android phones where you should connect it 'as a camera' in order for the PC to recognize the device. (It won't detect them otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Download mobogenie3 setup and connect your device ,mobogenie3 will automatically download your device driver and install it .